# GSoC 2016: Social Media Integration

Tags: gsoc, civicrm-buildkit

I'm a third year student studying B Tech in Computer Science and Engineering and Social Media Integration project caught my interest. I have an experience in Social Login integration on a PHP website. So, I believe this project is right for me.

I have already setup a local server and setup buildkit in it. And I have started to look into documentation. Further guidance on project specifics would be a great help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the job is to try shaping more precisely what your project will be, and discuss it with your mentor and the community.

Have you contacted directly the potential mentors? our irc channel is a good place to hang out and have more interactive discussions

In general, the more active you are in the community (eg trying to ask or answer specific questions, see what issues are left and looking for fix, being on irc...), the easier and faster it's going to be up to speed (and in your specific case, that your candidacy and project is selected)

Comment: Yes. I have been contacting potential mentors. But someone of the projects have not listed it's potential mentors.

Comment: aah, I will check with the mentors to be sure there is a least a contact point